# fading everything but div out like blockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fiddle here that has a big blue div. When i click the button, i'd like to select everything but the div and fade it out.

I've tried things like `$("body :not('#myBody')").css({opacity : '0.1'});` and things like this but nothing has worked yet.

I've also looked through the blockUI code, but couldn't quite comprehend it.

How do you all fade background elements out?[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/bVsnP/)

Comment: You missed something... `$("body *:not('#myBody')").css({opacity : 0.1 });`

Comment: @Archer--if you are referring to the `*` as missing, that is not needed for the `:not` to work (it is basically implied by the naked selector). If you refer to something else missing, then please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the wrong id and quotes around your opacity. [This fiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/bVsnP/8/) with this code:

```
 $("body :not('#box')").css({opacity: 0.1});
```